# Why reducer throws ReferenceError?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

This my first version, but it didn't work well with Next.js:

```
import { createReducer } from '../storeUtils';
import { SET_PRODUCT_DEPARTMENTS } from '../actions/productActions';

const initialState = {
  productDepartments: []
};

function setProductDepartments(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    productDepartments: action.payload
  };
}

export default createReducer(initialState, {
  [SET_PRODUCT_DEPARTMENTS]: setProductDepartments
});
```

In this case when I write "next build" it throws this error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SET_PRODUCT_DEPARTMENTS' before initialization
```

But in this case everything good:

```
import { SET_PRODUCT_DEPARTMENTS } from '../actions/productActions';

const initialState = {
  productDepartments: []
};

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_PRODUCT_DEPARTMENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                productDepartments: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default productReducer;
```

**Tell me what was the problem between these two?**